# Android Studio Bumblebee crashes frequently

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem and figured a way to deal with it.

Android Studio Bumblebee crashes randomly and frequently. There is no pattern. It crashes when I do something (e.g., editing code) or sometimes when I do nothing. It can crash soon after I start AS or after I use it for a little while. It crashes once every hour or so on average.

Are there any parameters that I can change to make AS stabler? Is there a good way to diagnose the crash?

I usually have over a dozen programs running on the same computer (Visual Studio, Outlook, browsers...). AS is the only program that crashes. All others work fine.

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.marketplace (211.7628.36), com.thoughtworks.gauge (211.6693.111), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), com.android.aas (3.5.1), com.google.mad-scorecard (1.2), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue until I disabled the Launch in tool window. Just go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator and disable the launch in a tool window checkbox.