# What is the correct way to install Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

I am sorry but I am really confused and leery now, so I am resorting to SO to get some clarity.

I am running Android Studio Bumblebee and saw a notification about a major new release wit the following text:

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 is a major new release and includes performance improvements, bug fixes and new features.
Intellij 2021.1.1 Platform Update
New Device Manager
ADB over Wi-Fi
Run Instrumented Tests in Android Studio using Gradle
Android Gradle Plugin Upgrade Assistant now updates API usage
Non-Transitive R classes on for new projects
Apple Silicon Support Update
Jank detection track in Profilers
Profileable app profiling support in Studio Profilers
Network Inspection and ability to capture Layout Inspector snapshots
Support for Compose semantics in the Layout Inspector
Interactive Preview
Animated Vector Drawables Preview
Updated Device picker for Design Tools
Important After updating, you need to restart Android Studio to apply any memory settings you migrate from an earlier version of the IDE.
```

When I click "[Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio)", I see "This minor update includes the following bug fixes:...". However, when I click "Download", a [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio) is opened. I am really puzzled by this because I thought a **minor update** would not require installing the entire thing. [The notes for Android Studio - Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/02/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-patch-1.html) indicates downloading the entire package is not needed:

> If you already have an Android Studio build on the Stable channel, you
> can get the update by clicking Help > Check for Update (Android Studio
>
> > Check for Updates on macOS). Otherwise, you can download it here.

I did a search and found people are having p[oor experiences with this update](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/sko495/android_studio_bumblebee_202111_patch_1_now/). Could anyone shed some light on this before I plunge into a potential disaster?

I am eager to update Bumblebee because [it keeps crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70896916/355456).

Comment: I agree completely - this is the second update for me with Bumblebee, the first required a full download which I went ahead and did, but now the same thing just for a patch? Something weird going on here!

Comment: Good news: A Google employee is now assigned to this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Android Studio Patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006400/how-to-install-the-bumblebee-2021-1-1-android-studio-patch)

Comment: It is the same answer by the author of the following answer.

Comment: @Hong The issue was fixed. Victory :)

Comment: @Denis Thank you for all the effort. I have just updated AS and run a few Gradle tasks. Everything appears fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This issue was fixed by Google** (10 February 2022).

You can now update Android Studio normally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to wait for a week or two and continue to live with the frequent crashes of Bumblebee. I am not even sure if the patch fixes this problem that is the main headache right now.