# How to install the Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Android Studio Patch?

Tags: android, android-studio, patch, android-studio-bumblebee

When I open Android Studio I receive a notification saying that an update is available:

```
The latest stable release of Android Studio is now available for download.

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 is a major new release and includes performance improvements, bug fixes and new features.

- Intellij 2021.1.1 Platform Update
- New Device Manager
- ADB over Wi-Fi
- Run Instrumented Tests in Android Studio using Gradle
- Android Gradle Plugin Upgrade Assistant now updates API usage
- Non-Transitive R classes on for new projects
- Apple Silicon Support Update
- Jank detection track in Profilers
- Profileable app profiling support in Studio Profilers
- Network Inspection and ability to capture Layout Inspector snapshots
- Support for Compose semantics in the Layout Inspector
- Interactive Preview
- Animated Vector Drawables Preview
- Updated Device picker for Design Tools

Important After updating, you need to restart Android Studio to apply any memory settings you migrate from an earlier version of the IDE.
Release Notes
```

However when I click on the Download button it opens a [web page](https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio) to re-download the whole program instead of updating it. It's a bit confusing because it's a minor update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to install Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999801/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-android-studio-bumblebee-2021-1-1-patch-1)

Comment: @AbhinavSuman Thank you very much, but the answer to this other question is also mine. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This issue was fixed by Google** (10 February 2022).

You can now update Android Studio normally.

Thank you all for helping to bring this problem to Google's attention.

Comment: I have just starred it.

Comment: Star button is on the left side of the tracker issue ID.

Comment: Right now this issue is assigned to someone form Google. Let's hope they'll fix that soon.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was fixed.
You can now update through the IDE without any webpage redirects or workarounds.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217880228

Answer (score 3):

Download and install JetBrains Toolbox. Android studio patch update will show in the toolbox list. Update through this. Hope its helpful.

Comment: It actually worked.

Comment: Did not work for me. JetBrains Toolbox, installed the patch alongside the existing version. Now I have the two versions working side by side. I want to have only one and updated.

Comment: This is because maybe you manually installed android studio in different folder. Toolbox will be helpful only for default installation folder is guess.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the issuetracker ([217880288](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217880228)):

> Workaround: delete manually only the "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"-folder and then install AS again. All your preferences will be restored because they are saved in your profile folder.

This worked for me.
However I for my part only renamed the old Android Studio folder and will keep it for a few Versions just to be have it in case of problems - but I didn't notice any problems yet.

P.S.: I readded the folder as exclusion from Antivirus, even if I do not remember well if this is still helping performance.

P.P.S.: Before I also tried the JetBrains Toolbox way to update AS, it said it installed the patch - however I still got the messages afterwards and it was still using old gradle.